# Database buffer cache in oracle

Tags: database, oracle12c

A block write occurs when:

1. The database is issued a shutdown command.
2. A full or partial checkpoint occurs.
3. A recovery time threshold is met.
4. A free block is needed and none are found after a given amount of time and many other reasons.

Why do we have so many points that trigger a block write-up. Why not just replace a dirty block from buffered cache through LRU algorithm only when a free block is needed. I think that can improve the performance. Any views on this?

Comment: What performance problem do you have?

Comment: None, but the first point that is database shutdown is valid, because if the block write is not done before shutdown we may loose it. But why the other three points. Why to make it more complex, when we simply can use LRU algorithm.